# Quebra de linha indesejada na saída no PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um código php que após realizar uma instrução, retorna uma String para o AJAX.

- O problema é que essa String está saindo com quebras de linhas que não existem. (Tanto no php quando no retorno do AJAX no JavaScript)

**Vejam o código:**

```html
<?php
 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 require_once("conexao.php");
  
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "", "pt_BR.utf-8");
 
 //CLASSE PARA VERIFICAR SE A EMPRESA JÁ POSSUI O BENEFÍCIO
 
 class Usuarios
 {    
  private $nome;
  private $idade;
  private $cidade;
  
  public function __get($atributo)
  {   
   return $this->$atributo;
  }
  
  public function __set($atributo, $valor)
  {   
   $this->$atributo = $valor;
  }  
       
  public function cadastrar()
  { 
   try
   {   
    //Conexão com o Banco de Dados (Futuramente podemos atribuir essa conexao a uma classe
    $c = new Conexao();
    $conexao = $c->conectar();
        
    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome,idade,cidade)VALUES(:nome,:idade,:cidade)";
    
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':nome',$this->nome);
    $stmt->bindValue(':idade',$this->idade);
    $stmt->bindValue(':cidade',$this->__get('cidade')); //Pode ser assim também
    
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = 0;
    $total = $stmt->rowCount();

    
    if($total > 0)
    {     
     echo "sucesso"; 
     die();
    }
    else
    {
     echo "falha"; 
     die();
    }
    
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
    //Verificando o erro ocorrido
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();    
   }
  } 

 
  
 }
  
  
 if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']))
 {
  $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
  $idade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'idade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $cidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  
  $usuarios = new Usuarios();
  
  $usuarios->__set('nome',$nome);
  $usuarios->__set('idade',$idade);
  $usuarios->__set('cidade',$cidade);

  $usuarios->cadastrar();
 }

?>
```

**Como estão as saídas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Com isso, a condição do If e else if abaixo (no JS) nunca são atendidas. Justamente por causa das quebras de linha.

```js
//EVENTO PARA QUANDO SUBMITAMOS O FORMULÁRIO 
$('#formulario-crud').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let formulario = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: "classes/classes.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",
    data: formulario.serialize(),


  }).done(function(data) {

    console.log(data);
    if (data == "sucesso") {
      alert("Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso");
    } else if (data == "falha") {
      alert("O usuário não foi cadastrado");
    }

  }).fail(function() {

  }).always(function(retornoempresas) {

  });

});
```

- Gostaria de fazer de uma forma que fosse identificar e resolver o problema na sua fonte. Gostaria de evitar coisas como trim(), etc... Gostaria de saber na verdade a causa das quebras de linhas. Vocês poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Verifique se antes da tag `<?php` de abertura do script não possui espaços ou linhas em branco, se estiverem presentes essas linhas serão incluídas na saída. Espaços ou linhas em branco após a tag `?>` de finalização do script também serão incluídos na saída. Verifique o mesmo nos arquios incluídos no seu script.

Comment: Ok, @AugustoVasques. terei acesso a esse código na parte da noite. Verificarei e testarei a sua sugestão. Grato!

Comment: @AugustoVasques , verifiquei essas situações e não resolveu. Muito estranho isso.

Comment: O meu código está exatamento como o disponibilizado aqui.

Comment: Até em outro arquivo, utilizando json_encode, isso está acontecendo.

Comment: Você verificou o `conexao.php`?

Comment: Pior que esse arquivo eu não verifiquei. Vou verificar e te dou um return.

Comment: Verifiquei tudo. Parece estar tudo certo e conforme as suas recomendações. Ainda estou com o problema. Se quiser o código todo eu posso lhe enviar ou algo assim.

Comment: Manda o código....

Comment: Me falaram que não é muito legal mandar códigos PHP pelo Fiddle, porém foi a única maneira que consigo mandar todas as partes (incluindo o HTML e o JS).  https://jsfiddle.net/fksjdnLt/

Comment: Eu preciso dos arquivos tal qual estão nos servidores. Pois por exemplo da forma que colocou as linhas 148, 149, 150 e 15, do arquivo html, seriam as responsáveis pelos espaços. Use um driver virtual ou coloque o projeto no github.

Comment: Certo, https://github.com/thiagopetherson/crud-oo.git

Comment: Criei um host para o [seu script](https://imgur.com/a/jdH1WCk), hora que tiver um tempo de folga dou uma olhada.

Comment: Está faltando o banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Use a função .trim() do JavaScript no retorno:

```
data.trim()
```

O .trim() elimina os espaços nas bordas da string.

Comment: Olá, Sam. Você como sempre prestativo. Obrigado. Mas cara, eu não gostaria de fazer dessa forma com o trim(). Eu gostaria de saber realmente o motivo do PHP estar dando essa saída com quebras de linhas no echo. Acho que fazendo com o trim(), estaríamos apenas 'tampando o sol com a peneira'. Já que provavelmente esse é um erro de PHP. Você não concorda ?

Comment: Cara, se vc quer que retorne uma string, o documento PHP que irá retornar essa string retorna possivelmente com espaços. O .trim() elimina esses espaços.

Comment: Opa, Sam. Mas isso não costuma acontecer comigo. A string que retorna para o Ajax sempre chega da maneira exata que sai do php.

Comment: Já tentou fazer um replace em possíveis quebras de linha, tipo: `data.replace(/\n/g, '').trim()`?